# how to make vim properly render RTL (Right to Left) languages

Tags: vimrc, macvim

I get this on my vim:

[image]

but the arabic translation is showing all messed up (in reverse orderlike dessem pu)

it should instead show like this (this is rendered in source tree:)
[image]

How to I make this work? (note: I'm using the terminal version of mac:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Sep 14 2017 18:28:18)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-1100
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminal
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +terminfo
+byte_offset     -gettext         -mzscheme        +termresponse
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +textobjects
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +timers
-clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        +title
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xpm
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xsmp
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_clipboard
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          -xterm_save
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
```

## update

arabic support is even worse on mlterm
[image]

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect your mlterm setup isn't working correctly. How did you compile/configure it? What does it look like if you `cat` the file outside of Vim?

Comment: The way I do it is to set a mapping to switch between `rtl` and `nortl`. Whenever you want to read or edit the Arabic-script part you just flip the whole text to rtl, including the Latin-script parts. I actually think this is better than a bidi solution since delimitiers and punctuation always maintain their logical order.

Comment: i simply fixed my problem by doing these maps:
`map <C-g> :set rightleft<CR>
map <C-h> :set norightleft<CR>`

Comment: @Rich i got it from this link: http://mlterm.sourceforge.net/bin.html

Comment: @abbood What does it look like if you `cat` the file in mlterm instead of opening it in Vim?

Answer (score 8):

Vim only supports displaying files containing mixed RTL and LTF text in a terminal which also supports this (such as [mlterm](http://mlterm.sourceforge.net/)). (You're not using GUI Vim, but I'll note for future readers that it is also not supported there.)

If your terminal does support this, you will also need to ensure that the `'termbidi'` option is set. This is set by default when Vim is running under mlterm, and unset otherwise.

See `:help 'termbidi'` and `:help arabic.txt` for more details.

Comment: see update to question

Comment: @abbood See my questions about your update.